# selenium in python having an error of: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: python, selenium

I am facing an error of selenium and chrome, this was working before but now it
is error and nothing I have changed, I tried to change selenium versions etc.. but still give me error while I work with chrome:

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium import webdriver
obj_Browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
obj_Browser.get("https://www.google.com/")
```

**PIP versions**:

webdriver-manager==3.3.0

selenium==3.141.0

**Full error that raise on line 3:**

```
Exception has occurred: ProtocolError
('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of simply passing:

```
google.com
```

to *`get()`* method you need to pass the *protocol* as well as follows:

```
https://www.google.com/
```

Effectively your line of code will be:

```
obj_Browser.get("https://www.google.com/")
```

Comment: The problem was not that because, the error is on line before while 'ChromeDriverManager' is being installed, it doesn't rich on get line.